# Debian Squeeze vzquota

Tags: vps, installation, debian-squeeze

Apparently, I got Debian Squeeze (Debian 6) to work on a VPS using debootstrap and chroot as described [here.](http://blog.kevin-k.com/2009-04-08/debian-lenny-auf-hosteurope-vps-installieren.html)
Subsequent installation of the harden, exim4, mysql-server packages failed partially.

Relevant information:

```
insserv: warning: script 'S10vzquota' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
insserv: warning: script 'vzquota' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service vzquota and stop-bootlogd if started
insserv:  loop involving service stop-bootlogd at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service vzquota at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 1
insserv: Starting vzquota depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vzquota depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vzquota and stop-bootlogd if started
insserv: Starting vzquota depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vzquota depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing exim4-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Any suggestions?

Keywords: vzquota debian squeeze installation vps, virtual private server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked `vzquota` and found that it is not conform to Debian 6.0 standard (init scripts) - quite naturally, as the provider does only support 5.0 at the time.

Before my fix:

```
#!/bin/sh
start() {
    [ -e "/dev/vzfs" ] || mknod /dev/vzfs b 0 115
    rm -f /etc/mtab >/dev/null 2>&1
    echo "/dev/vzfs / reiserfs rw,usrquota,grpquota 0 0" > /etc/mtab
    mnt=`grep -v " / " /proc/mounts`
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo "$mnt" >> /etc/mtab
    fi 
}
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  *)
    exit
esac
```

I prepended the following part to /etc/init.d/vzquota (do not forget to remove the second shabang line):

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:                 vzquota
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:             $local_fs $syslog
# Should-Stop:              $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:            0 1 2 3 4 5 6
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:        Fixed(?) vzquota init script
### END INIT INFO
```

And the installations succeeded. But after a reboot to verify my changes, I found out that the original file took over again.

Maybe someone else can suggest a more durable solution.

**Edit0:** As I finally decided to file a bug report, I found [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=594783). So the workaround I suggest can be useful for people without access to the files that have to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't modify the OpenVZ sh script that creates that file, you can just do something like this:

- 1: cp /etc/init.d/vzquota /etc/init.d/vzquota.original (don't needed, but it's always useful to have backups)
- 2: Just edit the vzquota file with nano or vi with the patch provided by benjamin and copy the modified file to /etc/init.d/vzquota.works
- 3: Create the file /etc/init.d/vzquotafix with this content:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
  # Provides:                 vzquotafix
  # Required-Start:
  # Required-Stop:
  # Should-Start:             $local_fs $syslog
  # Should-Stop:              $local_fs $syslog
  # Default-Start:            2 3 4 5
  # Default-Stop:             0 1 6
  # Short-Description:        Fix for vzquota init script
  ### END INIT INFO
  set -e
  cat /etc/init.d/vzquota.works > /etc/init.d/vzquota
  exit 0
  ```
- 4: chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vzquotafix
- 5: update-rc.d vzquotafix defaults

At every restart, this script replaces the broken vzquota file created by OpenVZ.