# vzquota not working /dev/vzfs missing on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: quota, virtuozzo

I have a problem with my Ubuntu VPS and the provider is unable and/or unwilling to help. The problem is that they supposedly support disk quotas, but it is not working on my server. `repquota -a` complains that `/dev/vzfs` does not exist, even though `/` is mounted on it.

After investigating the problem for hours, I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/248325/debian-squeeze-vzquota/248326#248326).

The `vzquota` script looks exactly like the one on my server **except** for the line that creates the device node, which does not exist in my version:

`[ -e "/dev/vzfs" ] || mknod /dev/vzfs b 0 115`

Could this be the solution? What would be the correct numbers for `mknod` to create the `vzfs` device? Can I get them from my provider? Or should they have been dynamically assigned by the virtualization software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigating, I realized I could get the correct device number via `stat --format '%D' /` and use that to create the missing node via `mknod /dev/vzfs b <major number from stat output> <minor number from stat output>`. And guess what, it works!!! I hope this helps others as well.

It's a shame that the provider wasn't able to tell me that. They told me I should switch to Debian for crying out loud! Well, if you want something done right, you have to do it yourself, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, too.

Only thing is, `stat --format '%D' /` gave me only *one* hex number.
(actually used `%d` to retrieve the dec number.)

As I got no MINOR number, I assumed a 0 and therefore did

```
 mknod /dev/vzfs b 43 0
```

which did the job and now quotas are working :)

*(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, STRATO vServer)*

Comment: `2b00` is technically one number, but it includes both the major and minor numbers.